# The request queue limit of the session is exceeded

Tags: sitecore-api

In my project media library has more than 200 child item in single folder. I'm trying to upload the image but facing the issue "The request queue limit of the session is exceeded".

Below configuration is already used in **Web.config**

```
 <add key="aspnet:RequestQueueLimitPerSession" value="25" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Request Queue Limit" error typically occurs when a large number of requests are being made to the server and the server is unable to process them all simultaneously. The default implementation of the ASP .NET Session State Module uses exclusive locking for each request from the same session. This means ASP .NET will only execute one request at a time from the same browser. Any other request will be locked by the Session State Module and will not be executed until the previous request is complete and it can obtain the exclusive lock.

Sitecore has a good KB article which describes this in more detail which can be found [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/858026). Here could be a few possible solutions to your problem:

- Sitecore have some settings regarding session management. One is the `pollingInterval`:

> PollingInterval – Specifies the time interval in seconds that the
> session-state provider uses to check if any sessions have expired.

The default polling interval is 2 seconds, which can lead to high load on the SQL server, and therefore a high CPU load, leading to longer response times, leading to the request queue not being processed.

Changing the `pollingInterval` is done 2 places, the SQL Session State Provider itself in the `web.config`, and the `\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Tracking\Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config config` file

You can change values to 60 seconds like this in the web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="false" timeout="20" customProvider="mssql">
  <providers>
    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql"
    sessionType="private"
    connectionStringName="session"
    pollingInterval="60"
    compression="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

And in `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config`:

```
<sharedSessionState defaultProvider="mssql">
  <providers>
    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider,Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql"
     connectionStringName="sharedsession"
     pollingInterval="60"
     compression="true"
     sessionType="shared" />
  </providers>
</sharedSessionState>
```

- Configure the [throttle concurrent requests per session](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/main/Documentation/compatibility/throttle-concurrent-requests-per-session.md)

In the .NET Framework 4.6.2 and earlier, ASP.NET executes requests with the same Sessionid sequentially and ASP.NET always issues the Sessionid through cookies by default. If a page takes a long time to respond, it will significantly degrade server performance just by pressing F5 on the browser. In the fix, we added a counter to track the queued requests and terminate the requests when they exceed a specified limit. The default value is 50. If the limit is reached, a warning will be logged in the event log, and an HTTP 500 response may be recorded in the IIS log.

To restore the old behaviour, you can add the following setting to your web.config file to opt out of the new behaviour.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:RequestQueueLimitPerSession" value="2147483647"/>
</appSettings>
```

- Switch the Private Session State to In-process mode and configure a Load Balancer to use sticky sessions:

i) In the `Web.config` file, find the `sessionState` element.

ii) Change the mode attribute value to `InProc`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue relates to Excessive load on ASP.NET Session State store, The default implementation of the ASP .NET Session State Module uses exclusive locking for each request from the same session. This means ASP .NET will only execute one request at a time from the same browser. Any other request will be locked by the Session State Module and will not be executed until the previous request is complete and it can obtain the exclusive lock.

To resolve it you can try below: [Excessive load on ASP.NET Session State store](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0858026)

Another solution is Sitecore sets this to the Default Session state behavior in the SitecoreControllerFactory for Sitecore MVC pages. This is a virtual method so this can be overridden to change the session state behavior:

```
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.SessionState;
 
namespace Foundation.Extensions.Factory
{
    public class ReadOnlySessionStateSitecoreControllerFactory : SitecoreControllerFactory
    {
        public ReadOnlySessionStateSitecoreControllerFactory(IControllerFactory innerFactory) : base(innerFactory)
        {
        }
 
        public override SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(requestContext, "requestContext");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(controllerName, "controllerName");
 
            if (controllerName.EqualsText(SitecoreControllerName))
            {
                return SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly;
            }
 
            return InnerFactory.GetControllerSessionBehavior(requestContext, controllerName);
        }
    }
}
```

An initialize pipeline processor needs to be created to set our new controller factory:

```
using Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Factory;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
 
namespace Foundation.Extensions.Processors.Initialize
{
    public class InitializeReadOnlySessionStateSitecoreControllerFactory : InitializeControllerFactory
    {
        protected Func<System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder> ControllerBuilder = () => System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder.Current;
 
        protected override void SetControllerFactory(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder controllerBuilder = ControllerBuilder();
            var controllerFactory = new ReadOnlySessionStateSitecoreControllerFactory(controllerBuilder.GetControllerFactory());
            controllerBuilder.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
        }
    }
}
```

Below XML file can be used to patch in this new pipeline processor

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Foundation.Extensions.Processors.Initialize.InitializeReadOnlySessionStateSitecoreControllerFactory, Foundation.Extensions" patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Setting the session state to readonly for Sitecore MVC pages can cause significant performance improvements and will help reduce the load on the session store as described in Sitecore’s KB article.

Credit and Reference: [Turn off Session State locking in Sitecore MVC pages](https://jeroen-de-groot.com/2020/03/31/turn-off-session-state-locking-in-sitecore-mvc-pages/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply increase the value of `aspnet:RequestQueueLimitPerSession`  settings. Max value `2147483647` is highest positive integer value. You can also keep to 200 or more.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:RequestQueueLimitPerSession" value="2147483647"/>
</appSettings>
```